# How to get db results into view

Tags: php

I have some php that gets data from the database, and I just want to get it into my view. I had this code from earlier where I just wanted 1 row, however now I want to get all the data into the view.

Do I have to make a loop and get each row into a string and keep appending to it?

here's the php:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM myData")) {
  $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
  if ($row_cnt > 0) {
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
     $data = $row["data"];
     echo $data;
} else {
     echo "no data";
}
  /* close result set */
  $result->close();
}
```

Comment: You could just echo `$row["data"];` no need to set it to a variable.

Comment: try changing "if ($row_cnt > 0) {"  to " while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {" if that works then you'll want to change your echo to separate the output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it, unless you need it in the code later. If that is the case store it to an array.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $row["data"];
     //$array[] = $row["data"];
}
```

Comment: do I have to declare an int to serve as the array index for each iteration `$index = 0; $array[index] = $row["data"];` like this?

Comment: this way print out each rows data in a loop not appending to `$data`

Comment: You don't have to, it will auto-append as written. If you want some particular index you can give it one.

Comment: and then i do `echo $array;` at the end? this is going back to a jQuery $ajax success call

Comment: It's already echoing, the AJAX will get the output from this without the array.

Comment: the array that's coming back seems to be a little off, I'm supposed to get words back, buts its giving me letters of those words one at a time, instead of each word one at a time. I'm using the `$array[]` by the way. In other words, instead of `['word','word2', 'word3']` I seem to be getting `['w', 'o','r','d']` etc. Also its printing out the brackets for some reason.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way :

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM myData")) {
  $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
  if ($row_cnt > 0) {
     While ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $data .= $row["data"]."<br>";
     }
     echo $data;
} else {
     echo "no data";
}
  /* close result set */
  $result->close();
}
```